# How to get the (un-) PublicationTarget for component UnPublish event in Tridion 2011?

Tags: c#, tridion, tridion-2011

I'm using Tridion 2011's Event System to perform some additional actions when un-publishing components. I'm using code found [here](http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/04/how-to-publish-stuff-programmatically.html) to publish a related component.

I'm registering my event handler as follows:

```
EventSystem.Subscribe<Component, UnPublishEventArgs>(
    RemoveAndRepublish, EventPhases.Initiated);
```

... and my handler method is as follows:

```
public void RemoveAndRepublish(Component cmp, UnPublishEventArgs args, 
                               EventPhases phase)
{
    // ... code to locate related component, and perform required actions...

    var instruction = new PublishInstruction(cmp.Session)
    {
        DeployAt = DateTime.Now,
        RenderInstruction = new RenderInstruction(cmp.Session)
        {
            RenderMode = RenderMode.Publish
        },
        ResolveInstruction = new ResolveInstruction(cmp.Session)
        {
            IncludeComponentLinks = true
        },
        RollbackOnFailure = true,
        StartAt = DateTime.MinValue
    };

    var target = args.Targets.FirstOrDefault();

    PublishEngine.Publish(new[] {related}, instruction, new[] {target});
}
```

My problem is that the `UnPublishEventArgs.Targets` property is an `IList<PublishingTarget>`, which at runtime turns out to be a `List<TargetType>`, and I need to get a `PublicationTarget` object to be able to call `PublishEngine.Publish(...)`.

My question is: is there a way to get the current (un-)PublicationTarget from an UnPublish event?

Can anyone offer any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to figure out the *PublicationTarget(s)* yourself from the *TargetType(s)*. Based on the *TargetType* and the *Publication* of the item you will need to iterate through the *PublicationTargets* to see if they allow your *Publication* to publish to them. This will (eventually) give you a list of *PublicationTargets*. Unfortunately that is quite a lot of work :(

All that said, do you really need the *PublicationTarget*? If you need to republish or un-publish items from the same Publication/Target combination, you should be able to parse the same *TargetType* array to the `PublishEngine.Publish(...)` method.

When I search the docs, I see the following override on PublishEngine():

```
PublishEngine.Publish Method (IEnumerable<(Of <(<'IdentifiableObject>)>)>, PublishInstruction, IEnumerable<(Of <(<'TargetType>)>)>, PublishPriority)

public static ICollection<PublishTransaction> Publish(
    IEnumerable<IdentifiableObject> items,
    PublishInstruction publishInstruction,
    IEnumerable<TargetType> targetTypes,
    PublishPriority priority
)
```

Comment: OK, the 2nd paragraph sounds more promising... could you give me an example?

The `PublishEngine.Publish` method takes an `IEnumerable<PublicationTarget>` not `IEnumerable<PublishingTarget>` .

Comment: Doh, totally didn't see the overload of `PublishEngine.Publish()` that takes an array of `TargetType`. Thanks!